# Get date and year from iso date in db

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have multiple array of isodate object as:

```
const apple = [{"readDetail":2021-04-17 14:23:26.978Z},{"readDetail":2021-02-18 14:23:26.978Z}, 
               {"readDetail":2019-04-18 14:23:26.978Z}]


Expected O/P = [  "April 2021","April 2020", "Feb 2021",]
```

Is it possible to convert to array of object to the expected O/P?

I tried looking for answers I could not find the answer. Please anyone has any question please let me know.

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: Break it into smaller steps. How to iterate array and parse the dates to a different format and how to `map()` an array to a new array with different elements structure. Both steps are easy to research and can then be rolled back into one step

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [`Date#toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString).

```js
const apple = [{"readDetail":'2021-04-17 14:23:26.978Z'},{"readDetail":'2021-02-18 14:23:26.978Z'}, 
               {"readDetail":'2019-04-18 14:23:26.978Z'}]
const res = apple.map(({readDetail})=>
   new Date(readDetail).toLocaleString('en', {month: 'long', year: 'numeric'}));
console.log(res);
```